How can I override PrimeNG p-divider color
Question is how can I override the color of primeng's p-divider in Angular. Using version 17.
Here is link to source code for p-divider component in PrimeNG
https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/tree/9003438e5f214c4239f64c6e3960dd05a8b07677/src/app/components/divider
Looking in chrome devtools I can see this style being applied which isn't in the source code for p-divider or its css file. If I override the color in chrome devtools it works as expected.
.p-divider.p-divider-horizontal:before {
    border-top: 1px #e5e7eb;
}

Like I said this code is not in source but it is in primeng's theme.css files for their various themes.
In devtools you can see this style also
.p-divider-solid.p-divider-horizontal:before {
    border-top-style: solid;
}

When i try to override the style of the border color in styles.scss or in my components css (using ng-deep) it overrides but then the border-top-style disappears and all p-dividers disappear in my component.
I have tried adding the border-top-style back both globally and through ng-deep and see in devtools but it has a line through it and is not applied. I can override any other styles with the p-divider like background color etc.. successfully but not the border-top-style. Usually this is an easy task to override the styles of PrimeNG but I am unsure what I am missing here? Any help would be greatly appreciated!! Thanks!

We have to include the border-type as solid when we override the class, when we set like how you mentioned, it makes the border-type as none so you are not able to see it.
.p-divider.p-divider-horizontal:before {
    border-top: 1px solid red !important;
}

Stackblitz Demo

Damn that was fast. Love the library thanks so much!
